# Where to find predefined classes, methods, functions and so on?

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell and programming in general. I came across the following `$Date = [datetime]::MinValue`. As I am learning PS I came across methods, functions and classes.

As I understand `[datetime]` is a class, now I am wondering how can I Get all classes in Powershell? I d like to take a look at them go through them get some awareness what to use as requirements are arising...

Is there also something more than cmdlet, methods, functions and classes (not that these wouldnt be enough)?

Comment: Link to the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/

Comment: @Thomas maybe it is straight forward for you...but I dont see any list here where I find this class [datetime] and others...I was searching in the searchfield and looking where it could be but havent found anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literal answer to your question would be to broad. Even if there was that single list of all classes, it would be so enormouse that you woldn't want to read it. Powershell can use .Net so there are thousends of classes, all of them separated in different namespaces. Take a look at the [Microsoft Doku of the System namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system?view=netcore-3.1) (`DateTime` is in there too).
So instead of learning all classes there are, start with these basic ones:

1. string
2. int / integer / int32
3. array
4. hashtable
5. PSObject / PSCustomObject

If you come across an object (see `help about_objects` the most important concept in PowerShell) and you want to know what it is, use `.GetType()` and use your favorite search engine to find the Microsoft Doku:

```
(Get-Date).GetType()
```

Btw. the `[datetime]` in `[datetime]::MinValue`is not a class but an accelerator. An accelerator is just an alias for a class. [Here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-find-powershell-type-accelerators/) you can read more about accelerators.

Comment: First of all thank you! My issue is how to organize the knowledge of Powershell to learn it..I had a requirement where I wanted the user to put in a date, however, I wanted to be sure he puts in a date and nothing else, so someone helped me with a loop and `[datetime]::MinValue`. Before that, I started to find a solution which wasnt good at all as there is an accelerator, therefore, I thought first to get used to the functions, methods, classes and so on before trying to find a bad solution by myself...